# Conversion to Unique and ordered string of numbers

Tags: r

If I had a dataframe that has a string of numbers separated by a comma in a column, how can I convert that string to an ordered and unique converted set in another column?

```
Month  String_of_Nums  Converted
May    3,3,2           2,3
June   3,3,3,1         1,3
Sept   3,3,3, 3        3
Oct    3,3,3, 4        3,4
Jan    3,3,4           3,4
Nov    3,3,5,5         3,5
```

I tried splitting up the string of numbers to get unique to work

```
strsplit(df$String_of_Nums,",")
```

but I end up with spaces in the character list. Any ideas how to efficently generate a Converted column? Also need to figure out how to operate on all elements of the column, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Month  String_of_Nums
May    '3,3,2'           
June   '3,3,3,1'         
Sept   '3,3,3,3'        
Oct    '3,3,3,4'        
Jan    '3,3,4'           
Nov    '3,3,5,5'", header = TRUE)

df1$converted <- apply(read.csv(text=as.character(df1$String_of_Nums), header = FALSE), 1, 
                       function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse = ","))

df1
  Month String_of_Nums converted
1   May          3,3,2       2,3
2  June        3,3,3,1       1,3
3  Sept        3,3,3,3         3
4   Oct       3,3,3, 4       3,4
5   Jan          3,3,4       3,4
6   Nov        3,3,5,5       3,5
```

Comment: Running into a problem when I try to use this with my larger dataset here. I am able to run this fine with the months dataframe but when I try to do this with the bigger dataset  the read.csv function collapses the numbers into strings (it does not do this with the months dataset) and creates a larger list than the original dataframe. I tried 'as.list' instead of 'as.character' but I get an error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to leave another way. As far as I see, Jay's example has `String_of_Nums` as factor. Given you said that `strsplit()` worked, I am assuming that you have `String_of_Nums` as character. Here I have the column as character as well. First, split each string (`strsplit`), find unique characters (`unique`), sort the characters (`sort`), and paste them (`toString`). At this point, you have a list. You want to convert the vectors in the list using `as_vector` from the `purrr` package. Of interest, I used benchmark to see how performance would be like to create a vector (i.e., `Converted`)

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

lapply(strsplit(mydf$String_of_Nums, split = ","),
           function(x) toString(sort(unique(x)))) %>% 
as_vector(.type = "character") -> mydf$out

#  Month String_of_Nums  out
#1   May          3,3,2 2, 3
#2  June        3,3,3,1 1, 3
#3  Sept        3,3,3,3    3
#4   Oct        3,3,3,4 3, 4
#5   Jan          3,3,4 3, 4
#6   Nov        3,3,5,5 3, 5


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
 jazz = lapply(strsplit(mydf$String_of_Nums, split = ","),
                   function(x) toString(sort(unique(x)))) %>% 
        as_vector(.type = "character"),

 jay = apply(read.csv(text=as.character(df1$String_of_Nums), header = FALSE), 1, 
                   function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse = ",")),

 times = 10000)

# expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
# jazz  358.913  393.018  431.7382  405.9395  420.1735 54779.29 10000
#  jay 1099.587 1151.244 1233.5631 1167.0920 1191.5610 56871.45 10000
```

**DATA**

```
  Month String_of_Nums
1   May          3,3,2
2  June        3,3,3,1
3  Sept        3,3,3,3
4   Oct        3,3,3,4
5   Jan          3,3,4
6   Nov        3,3,5,5

mydf <- structure(list(Month = c("May", "June", "Sept", "Oct", "Jan", 
"Nov"), String_of_Nums = c("3,3,2", "3,3,3,1", "3,3,3,3", "3,3,3,4", 
"3,3,4", "3,3,5,5")), .Names = c("Month", "String_of_Nums"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```